# Javascript setTimeout doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a simple code that writes some sentences letter by letter and then delete them one by one.
I want to make a delay after writing each letter and add the next one but with the code it just writes **hellobye** after waiting for 1000 ms.

```js
const writeSentences = () => {
  const sentences = ["hello", "bye"];
  const config = {
    writeDelay: 1000,
    removeDelay: 100,
    readingDelay: 250
  };
  const element = document.getElementById("sentence");

  sentences.forEach((sentence) => {
    sentence.split("").forEach((letter) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        element.innerHTML += letter;
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", writeSentences());
```

```html
<span id="sentence"></span>
```

Comment: Not directly your issue, but remove the parenthesis of `writeSentences()` when you passed it to `addEventListener()`. Otherwise it will be executed immediately instead of when the DOM content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the `delay` in a variable and add the delay for next element as `last delay + 1000` .

```
let delay = 1000;
  const getDelay = () => {
    delay += config.writeDelay;
    return delay;
  };
```

```js
const writeSentences = () => {
  const sentences = ["hello", "bye"];
  const config = {
    writeDelay: 1000,
    removeDelay: 100,
    readingDelay: 250
  };
  const element = document.getElementById("sentence");
  
  let delay = 1000;
  const getDelay = () => {
    delay += config.writeDelay;
    return delay;
  };
  
  sentences.forEach((sentence) => {
    sentence.split("").forEach((letter) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        element.innerHTML += letter;
      }, getDelay());
    });
  });
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", writeSentences());
```

```html
<span id="sentence"></span>
```